# Are plpgsql functions atomic?

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, atomic

I'm wondering about the atomicity of a `plpgsql` function call, as well as nesting calls:

So for example, I'd like to put two pieces of information into two different tables:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_registration(
  i_email TEXT,
  i_nickname TEXT
) RETURNS JSONB AS $$
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    o_account "UserAccount";
    o_identity "UserIdentity";
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "UserAccount"  (nickname) VALUES (i_nickname) RETURNING * INTO o_account;
    INSERT INTO "UserIdentity" (email) VALUES (i_email) RETURNING * INTO o_identity;
    RETURN jsonb_build_object(
        'account',row_to_json(o_account), 
         'identity',row_to_json(o_identity)
    );
  END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

will calling `email_registration('hello', 'world')` ever result in `hello` being in the `UserAccount` table and `world` missing in the `UserIdentity` table?

---

Also, if the two inserts where refactored out into functions, will the function call still be atomic?

ie.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION email_registration(
  i_email TEXT,
  i_nickname TEXT
) RETURNS JSONB AS $$
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    o_account "UserAccount";
    o_identity "UserIdentity";
  BEGIN
    o_account := insert_email(i_email);
    o_identity := insert_nickname(i_nickname);
    RETURN jsonb_build_object(
        'account',row_to_json(o_account), 
         'identity',row_to_json(o_identity)
    );
  END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: A function runs in the transaction of the caller. And that transaction is atomic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function always runs in the single transaction that was active when the function call was started, so either all statements succeed or all statements fail. That is guaranteed.

There are other things that could cause an `INSERT` not to have an effect, for example a row level `BEFORE` trigger that returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, functions([PL/pgSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) and [SQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html)) are atomic. A function is run in a transaction so if there is error, the transaction is rollbacked.

For example, you create `my_func()` function which sets `5` to `my.var` then can cause `division by zero` error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
SET my.var = 5; -- Here
RETURN 1/value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

First, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_func(1)` then `5` is set to `my.var` successfully as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# SELECT my_func(1);
 my_func
---------
       1
(1 row)
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 5
(1 row)
```

Now, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_func(0)` then `division by zero`  error occurs, then `my.var` is still `2` as shown below because `my_func()` function is rollbacked:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# SELECT my_func(0);
ERROR:  division by zero
...
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 2
(1 row)
```

Comment: What would happen if you were to `SELECT my_func(2), my_func(0);` in the same statement though?