# how to force a postgres function to not be in a transaction

Tags: postgresql

Following on from [Are plpgsql functions atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132466/are-plpgsql-functions-atomic/66132606#66132606), I'm wondering if the inverse if possible.

I want to have two connections (C1 and C1) calling a function (F) that runs two transactions (T1 and T2). I don't care if the transactions are interleaved when both are calling (F)

```
<T1 on C1> 
<T1 on C2>
<T2 on C1> 
<T2 on C2>
```

Is this possible to setup via settings in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is always running inside a single transaction.

A database session can only have a single open transaction at a time. However, there are subtransactions (which are *not* independent from the containing transaction) and prepared transactions (which hang around incomplete, but no work can be done in them).

Comment: so not possible is the answer?

Comment: I don't understand your wish in detail, but "calling a function (F) that runs two transactions (T1 and T2)" is simply out of the question.