# does dblink use a different session when performed on the same database?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to get around the limitations from [how to force a postgres function to not be in a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169487/how-to-force-a-postgres-function-to-not-be-in-a-transaction/).

I'd like to execute two seperate transactions within a single function and am wondering if using dblink calls on loopback will solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your use case but "separate transactions" is just an abstraction. No matter what you do those will be synchronous, i.e. it's still a single timeline, where nothing can happen in-between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dblink query uses its own connection created explicitly by [`dblink_connect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html) or implicitly when a connection info string is delivered in a dblink exec command. In the sense of transactions, you can consider it independent of the transaction in which it ran.

Example setup:

```sql
create table test(id int, str text);
insert into test values(1, '');
```

Two transactions inside an outer one:

```sql
begin;
select dblink_connect('db1', 'dbname=test');
select dblink_connect('db2', 'dbname=test');

select dblink_exec('db1', 'begin');
select dblink_exec('db1', 'update test set str = ''db1'' where id = 1');
select dblink_exec('db1', 'commit');  -- UPDATE!

select dblink_exec('db2', 'begin');
select dblink_exec('db2', 'update test set str = ''db2'' where id = 1');
select dblink_exec('db2', 'rollback');

select dblink_disconnect('db1');
select dblink_disconnect('db2');

rollback;
```

Despite the last rollback, the update in transaction `db1` was successful:

```sql
select * 
from test;

 id | str
----+-----
  1 | db1
(1 row)
```

Note that while transactions are essentially independent, sessions are not. The commands in two internal sessions are executed one after the other in a linear manner, and no concurrency can be achieved. A possible conflict would create a deadlock.

Comment: That's just a de jure situation, de facto these will be completely linked and totally dependent as if it was a one transaction.

Comment: @user64204 - see the updated answer with some explanations.